# passing a dictionary to an ngResource for multiple URL parameters

Tags: angularjs

I have the following factory method in an angularjs application.

```
var mod = angular.module('scheduleApp.services', ['ngResource', 'ui.bootstrap']);

mod.factory('SchedulesFactory', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://devhost\\:8080/api/schedule', {}, {
        query: { method: 'GET', isArray: false},
        create: { method: 'POST' },
        getPage: {  method: 'GET', 
                    params: {page: '@page', 
                                q: {"order_by": [{"field": "@fieldName", "direction": "@direction"}]}} },
        getPageSorted: {method: 'GET'}

    });
});
```

In my GET handler, getPage, I would like to pass a dictionary from which I can resolve three variables, page, fieldName, and direction.

```
var n = {};
n.page = $scope.currentPage;
n.fieldName = $scope.fieldName
n.direction = $scope.direction
```

But this doesn't work. When I examine my GET URL string, angularjs doesn't replace the fieldName and direction identifiers with the values in my dictionary. The following URL scheme is GET'ed:

/api/schedule?direction=asc&fieldName=id&page=1&q={"order_by":[{"field":"@fieldName","direction":"@direction"}]}

Here is how I invoke the getPageSorted routine:

```
var n = {};
n.page = $scope.currentPage;
n.fieldName = "id"
n.direction = "asc"
SchedulesFactory.getPage(n, function(object) {
    console.log(object);
    $scope.schedules = object.objects;
    $scope.totalItems = object.num_results;
});
```

Does anyone have an recommendations how I can specifically address this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe ng-resource supports what you are trying to do. You will need to put a function in place of "q" and do your own changes there.